# Fastest way to find dictionary strings in a text

Tags: string, algorithm

I have a text file and dictionary. The dictionary consists of a list of exactly 8-chars long words. I go through the text file and search the dictionary every 8 chars ("sliding window").

Currently, I use python dictionary data structure as the look up table. It has amortized look up time of 0(1), but I wonder if there exists faster algorithms/data structures that uses the specific nature/structure of the problem.

Comment: Rabin-Karp is an algorithm that was devised specifically for matching a large number of fixed length patterns and it's pretty good. I don't know if there are any better but it sounds like R-K is exactly what you need.

Comment: Not sure this is any faster, but you could make a disjunctive regular expression from the word in the dict and match that regex with the text.

Comment: By "words", do you mean actual words, that are delimited by whitespace and punctuation, or just character sequences, like in genetic code?

Comment: @tobias_k That's more or less what the Aho-Corasick algorithm does. :)

Comment: @tobias_k: I mean character sequence

Comment: Is the dictionary fixed and the text file changes? Or is it the other way around?

Comment: fgrep constructs a DFA a la Aho-Corasick, and uses it to scan the input stream/file. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm

Comment: One problem with the regex-appraoch might be, that it does not handle overlapping matches well (might depend on the implementation, not sure).

Comment: @biziclop: the dictionary is fixed

Comment: @Roy For a fixed dictionary, Aho-Corasick is probably the best algorithm as you can pre-build the finite state machine used for matching and then re-use it for all searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try aho-corasick multiple pattern matcher. It construct a finite state machine with a trie and breadth-first search the first occurrence of the longest prefix that is also a suffix of a dictionary string. You can try my implementation in php at https://phpahocorasick.codeplex.com. It also augment the algorithm to search for wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Full text search to do it such as Apache Sorl, Elastich Search.

But you can use http://lunrjs.com/ for client side.